# JTable getEditingColumn() is returning previously edited column. Is there any way to get currently editing column?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I use the below code to focus first column

```
jTable1.requestFocusInWindow();
jTable1.changeSelection(jTable1.getRowCount()-1, 0, false, false);
jTable1.editCellAt(jTable1.getRowCount()-1, 0);
jTable1.setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(true); 
jTable1.getEditorCo‌​mponent().requestFoc‌​us();
```

[image]

after clicking and editing 4th or another cell, when i edit the first column ,getEditingColumn() returning the last edited column

eg:

> After selecting column 4 , on editing getEditingColumn() returns 3

[image]

Then I select !st column and getEditingColumn() returns 3

[image]

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I've had some difficulty with getting the cell editor to be focusable in the past.  Partly because the there is a delay between the time you ask the cell to be edited and when the cell is actually editable.  From (foggy) memory, I think I had a custom cell editor which trigger the request at different stages of the process

Comment: I'm guessing your are using a custom editor and haven't invoked stopEditing on the editor.

Comment: I solved the problem. It was because, I used separate custom editor class object for each column. I declared an object of custom editor and gave to all columns. Then the problem solved. Thanks for responding